# How to catch an ImportError non-recursively?

Tags: python, importerror

Say we want to import a script named `user.py`, which may fail.

```
try:
   import user
except ImportError:
   logging.info('No user script loaded.')
```

How can we make sure to only catch the possible import failure of `user.py` itself, and not of the imports that may be contained in `user.py`?

Comment: This related post provides a nicer solution for `python3.3` that also works for dynamic imports: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28798208/how-to-catch-an-importerror-non-recursively-dynamic-import

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check to see if the current traceback is part of a chain of tracebacks:

```
import sys

try:
    import user
except ImportError:
    if sys.exc_info()[2].tb_next:
        raise

    logging.info('No user script loaded.')
```

If there is an `ImportError` in `user`, `sys.exc_info()[2].tb_next` will point to it.

Answer (score 1):

You could look at the arguments:

```
try:
   import user
except ImportError as exception:
    if 'user' == exception.args[0][16:]:
        logging.info('No user script loaded.')
```

This ensures you'll only log that message when the user script fails to be imported.

Although, it can be argued that failing to import one of the imports in `user` also implies that it can't import `user` (which means you'd need to log the message anyway).

Comment: This approach is a little fragile, as it'll raise a false positive for `No module named not_user`.

Comment: @Blender I've updated it so that the module name needs to match `user` exactly. Other than that I agree it's fragile in the sense that line 2 and line 4 need to contain the same module name.