# How to catch an ImportError non-recursively? (dynamic import)

Tags: python-3.x, import, importerror, python-import

Say we want to import a script dynamically, i.e. the name is constructed at runtime. I use this to detect plugin scripts for some program, so the script may not be there and the import may fail.

```
from importlib import import_module
# ...
subpackage_name = 'some' + dynamic() + 'string'
try:
    subpackage = import_module(subpackage_name)
except ImportError:
    print('No script found')
```

How can we make sure to only catch the possible import failure of the plugin script itself, and not of the imports that may be contained *inside* the plugin script?

Side note: [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20459166/how-to-catch-an-importerror-non-recursively) is related, but is about static imports (using the `import` keyword), and the provided solutions don't work here.

Comment: Why don't you want to catch errors from imports inside the plugin?

Comment: If there is an import error in the script I want to know that. I don't want it to pass silently, saying no scripts were found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Python 3.3, `ImportError` objects have had `name` and `path` attributes, so you can catch the error and inspect the name it failed to import.

```
try:
    import_module(subpackage_name)
except ImportError as e:
    if e.name == subpackage_name:
        print('subpackage not found')
    else:
        print('subpackage contains import errors')
```

Comment: I wasn't aware of this improvement. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

`ImportError`s in Python have <s>messages you can read</s> `name` attributes you can use if you have the exception object:

```
# try to import the module
try:
    subpackage = import_module(subpackage_name)

# get the ImportError object
except ImportError as e:

    ## get the message
    ##message=e.message

    ## ImportError messages start with "No module named ", which is sixteen chars long.
    ##modulename=message[16:]

    # As Ben Darnell pointed out, that isn't the best way to do it in Python 3
    # get the name attribute:
    modulename=e.name

    # now check if that's the module you just tried to import
    if modulename==subpackage_name:
        pass

        # handle the plugin not existing here

    else:
        # handle the plugin existing but raising an ImportError itself here

# check for other exceptions
except Exception as e:
    pass
    # handle the plugin raising other exceptions here
```

Comment: Yeah, the new name attribute does the trick better, but you get my upvote anyway.

Comment: @Chiel92 Yeah, I usually use Python 2.